# Is it possible to make this BJT-based voltage limiter more \$\beta\$-independent and temperature stable?

Tags: bjt, leakage-current

The following circuit limits the rail voltage to slightly above **Vref**, by drawing a lot of current, when the rail exceeds **Vref**. The BUF Block represents a supply such as LDO, Reference or other regulator. On paper, it works well to replace various safety Zeners and stuff, of which there is never the right value available/in stock.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fVJjLa.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

However, I see two problems: it depends a lot on the transistor \$\beta\$ (\$\approx\beta^4\$) and when Q1 leaks current (due to enhanced temperature), that leakage will be amplified by \$\approx\beta^3\$, which can quickly lead to 10s mA of leakage.

**Can anyone think of a fix for these issues?**

Comment: 1) why is 2 transistors not enough (just Q1 and Q2)? 2) If you do not limit the current that Vsup can supply, the transistors will **destroy** themselves when Vsup > Vlim + 0.7 V 3) Why not simply use a zener diode / diodes in series / TVS etc.. like everyone else? 4) why not simply use an LDO (series regulator)?

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie 1) because I don't have singles or mixed-type BJT packages, also fewer transistors will limit a bit later, which can be too late if there is only little headroom until abs max rating 2) I am aware, but it's not an argument: the same goes for all shunt type limiters.. 3) see (1) 4) LDOs can also overshoot, so may require voltage limiting if abs max rating is close.

Comment: what is this supposed to do?

Comment: *also fewer transistors will limit a bit later* So you think the circuit will clamp **faster** with 4 transistors instaed of 2? I am going to state that 2 transistors will be faster (less delays in the circuit) and 2 transistors will be fast enough anyway. But feel free to prove me wrong.

Comment: *4) LDOs can also overshoot...* Then choose LDO with enough headroom, also add decoupling capacitors to limit voltage spikes.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie not faster wrt time, but wrt to mVs above the reference. I have slightly modified the schematic, to get the intent across hopefully a bit better. The circuit is intended to shunt only load side positive excursions of Vrail.

Comment: *not faster wrt time, but wrt to mVs above the reference.* Then write that. a couple of BJTs will never be a precise / good / reliable reference. Andy's suggestion is a good one: a Vref with a comparator, look at the TL431.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie *a couple of BJTs willnever be a precise / good / reliable reference*: Just to be clear, in case the intent is still not clear. The BJTs are not meant to do anything precise. Vref is a precision voltage from elsewhere, and BUF is a Buffer with only a few mVs offset. However Vrail can attain higher values due to a number of reason and the BJTs are only there to shunt this excess and not allow Vrail to climb more than ~400 mV

Comment: This is the wrong way to deal with overvoltage spikes. Since this type of overvoltage is likely generated within the regulator you need to reduce the input voltage NOT increase the output current. Increasing the output current will cause the regulator to INCREASE the output voltage until it reaches an overcurrent point ....then it's likely to enter overcurrent shutdown and start to cycle up again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *Can anyone think of a fix for these issues?*

The fix is a precision shunt regulator based around an emitter follower PNP  power transistor being driven by an op-amp. The op-amp has a precision voltage reference on the non-inverting pin and the inverting input is connected to your raw supply: -

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I've never used those, but I think they would nicely fill the role of a voltage limiter when a Zener is not stiff enough.

Comment: Just one more question to your experience before gratefully accepting. What timescale of spikes can I expect to catch and not catch with such a precision shunt ?

Comment: The faster the op-amp the better. If you can hang capacitance across the circuit supply it will improve things. Why not simulate it and push it to its limits?

Comment: *What timescale of spikes can I expect to catch and not catch with such a precision shunt ?* Experienced EEs add **decoupling capacitors** to "catch" the spikes that are faster than the active circuit can handle. Question is, how much spiking (voltage) and dV/dt (voltage rising speed) can your circuit generate / handle? That's a tough question, I know.

Comment: Yeah thanks Andy and @Bimpelrekkie Somehow I was too intrigued with details that I didn't see the obvious solution i.e. opamp for the stiff limiting and capacitors *blush*.

Answer (score 0):

This circuit might work in a 'DC' mode; however it will not work well (or at all) in practice because of AC (loop gain) stability.

Note that this circuit is not particularly precise -- the clamping point is about one VBE (0.7 V) above the reference.

One of the skills applied in analog circuit design is to use circuits and topologies that reduce dependency on specific component performance -- transistor beta; specific values of capacitors, temperature variations etc.

For example, feedback circuits do this by replacing imprecise forward gain by a regulated gain which comes from a resistor divider (e.g. precise and stable), and a forward gain stage which has 'sufficiently high' gain so swamp out any sensitivity. Opamps achieve low offset by using differential techniques to cancel out the VBE (or VTH) variations in individual transistors.

For circuits like this, the wide variation in beta; the temperature effects and huge dynamic range of currents will make the behaviour quite unpredictable. Specifically, the wide dynamic range will likely make the whole circuit (which is a regulator) unstable at some load ranges.

The general technique to eliminate this type of issue is to bias the devices so that they run some (small) current even when the clamp is not active; when the clamp becomes active, the change in currents will not affect the characteristics (beta, bandwidth) as dramatically. In general this is not easy and takes a lot of design skill, analysis and effort to make a robust and reliable (i.e. non-oscillating) circuit.

1. 4 transistors is likely excessive -- stabilizing 4 gain stages is extremely difficult. You don't need 4 devices, and 2 (maybe 3) should be enough. Some tradeoffs depend on the ratio of current you need to clamp vs. the quiescent current you can afford to use. Given that 0.7 V of error is apparently enough, likely 2 transistors is sufficient.
2. The general way to reduce the dynamic range is to bias the devices. in this circuit the starting point is to put a resistance between B and E of each device -- say 0.7/R is 1/100 of the expected collector current.
3. So for a starting point, remove Q1, Q3, and put ~ 1k between B and E of Q4. Check AC stability by applying different pull-up currents (what is the expect source of this pull-up ?). Be sure to include the output decoupling capacitor(s) on the rail.

Comment: I agree with most but please note, that "0.7V" is not precise enough. That is why there were 4 BJTs in the sketch. They will sink already more than 10 mA when 200-300 mV above the reference. Agree about everything else about stability etc. I will try Andy's opamp based circuit.

Comment: *that "0.7V" is not precise enough. That is why there were 4 BJTs in the sketch* The "4 BJTs" aren't going to help being "more precise". I'd say that they're only making things worse. But feel free to prove me wrong by showing how those 4 BJTs make this "more precise" so I can learn something new. What I think you mean is that you want a "sharper" knee voltage where the clamp starts to draw current. Also a Vbe is never going to be "precise" as it has a -2 mV/K temperature coeffcient.

Comment: the 4 BTs add more current gain (if you needed it), but don't make the 'trigger' point particularly precise. operating at 200-300 mV above the reference means extremely low currents in the devices (pA or nA; if the models are correct at these currents) and will make the circuit a) extremely slow; and b) likely unstable (e.g. it will oscillate).

Comment: Yes, my fear of its dodgy stability is what spawned this thread. I know its not *precise*. It is not meant to be. I was just using jp314's word "precise" in my comment... Well nvm, pointless argument as Andy has already already added a useful solution.